# Как сбросить конкретные данные в PHP сессии, не затронув остальные!

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Проблема в том, что собрать данные в PHP сессии могу. Но вот очистить конкретную "строку" данных не получается. То есть сбросить что-то одно, не стирая и не убивая саму сессию.

Пример на скриншоте, к примеру, что хотел бы сбросить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода, который использую

```
    <?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    
    session_start();
    
    if (isset($_REQUEST['product1'])) {
    $_SESSION['product1'] = $_REQUEST['product1'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    }

?>

<html>

<br><h1>СТРАНИЦА 2</h1></br>

</br>

<form method="GET">
<!-- Кнопка 1 с переменной: name="submit_ok" -->
<div class="cart_btn">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="product1" value="Кнопка 1" style="font-size:16px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру вот так

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION); // array(0) {}


$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
$_SESSION['test1'] = 'test1';
var_dump($_SESSION); //array(2) {["test"]=> string(4) "test" ["test1"]=>string(5) "test1" }

unset($_SESSION['test1']);
var_dump($_SESSION); // array(1) { ["test"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!